# How does WebRTC decide which TURN Servers to Use

Tags: javascript, webrtc, stun, turn

Branching off this question [WebRTC - How many STUN/TURN servers do I need to specify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23292520/webrtc-how-many-stun-turn-servers-do-i-need-to-specify/23307588?noredirect=1#comment41283996_23307588)

How does WebRTC determine which TURN servers to use when more than one is provided?

Comment: It organizes the ICE candidates gathered by each one given their [priority set during the ice gathering stage](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5245#section-4.1.2) and this is implementation specific I believe(meaning FF and Chrome prefer different candidate types).

Comment: @BenjaminTrent thank you very much, I had not stumbled upon that priority value in the RFC. If you like, add this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Every Ice candidate is given a priority when it is gathered. It is a mixture of a couple of things and I believe that each platform(Chrome, FireFox, etc.) has their own preferences.

Here is a [link to the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5245#section-4.1.2) explaining how priorities are to be generated. Each priority is guaranteed to be unique as the candidate ID should be unique(if the RFC is followed). So, you should never have a tie in priorities. Those with higher priorities are tried first, if a connection cannot be made with them, then the next in line is used.

Quote from the RFC Regarding priority:

> When using the formula, an agent computes the priority by determining
> a preference for each type of candidate (server reflexive, peer
> reflexive, relayed, and host), and, when the agent is multihomed,
> choosing a preference for its IP addresses.  These two preferences
> are then combined to compute the priority for a candidate.  That
> priority is computed using the following formula:

```
    priority = (2^24)*(type preference) +
               (2^8)*(local preference) +
               (2^0)*(256 - component ID)
```

> The type preference MUST be an integer from 0 to 126 inclusive, and
> represents the preference for the type of the candidate (where the
> types are local, server reflexive, peer reflexive, and relayed).  A
> 126 is the highest preference, and a 0 is the lowest.  Setting the
> value to a 0 means that candidates of this type will only be used as
> a last resort.  The type preference MUST be identical for all
> candidates of the same type and MUST be different for candidates of
> different types.  The type preference for peer reflexive candidates
> MUST be higher than that of server reflexive candidates.  Note that
> candidates gathered based on the procedures of Section 4.1.1 will
> never be peer reflexive candidates; candidates of these type are
> learned from the connectivity checks performed by ICE.
>
> The local preference MUST be an integer from 0 to 65535 inclusive.
> It represents a preference for the particular IP address from which
> the candidate was obtained, in cases where an agent is multihomed.
> 65535 represents the highest preference, and a zero, the lowest.
> When there is only a single IP address, this value SHOULD be set to
> 65535.  More generally, if there are multiple candidates for a    particular component for a particular media stream that have the same
> type, the local preference MUST be unique for each one.  In this
> specification, this only happens for multihomed hosts.  If a host is
> multihomed because it is dual stack, the local preference SHOULD be
> set equal to the precedence value for IP addresses described in RFC
> 3484 [RFC3484].
>
> The component ID is the component ID for the candidate, and MUST be
> between 1 and 256 inclusive.

You can see the turn server ip and port is shown in a relay candidate. The following is derived from  [the RFC page 82](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5245.txt) and [webrtc hacks](http://webrtchacks.com/sdp-anatomy/).

```
a=candidate:2157334355<ID> 2<Component> udp<NetType> 33562367<Prioirty> 180.6.6.6<NAT pub IP> 54278<NAT pub Port> typ relay<Means it needs to be relayed through Turn> raddr 46.2.2.2<Relay address of turn> rport 38135<relay port of turn> generation 0
```

Comment: It seems that Chrome (Blink) also modifies the local preference by distance/latency. When using multiple turn servers, closer ones usually have a much higher priority.

Comment: @Mantriur did you ever find out more about that? I have tried to replicate that behaviour and wasn't able to (but maybe it has changed in the last 7 years!), and looking through basic_port_allocator.cc in the Chromium source I can't see where latency/RTT would be taken into account when setting the candidate priority.

Comment: @jbg Other than Benjamin's comment on the question, I have no idea. We're using websockets  to guesstimate latency and then only offer the two closest ones to the browser.