# How to influence the priority of TURN servers?

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn

The RFC states that the browser has to assign a priority to ICE candidates. In my understanding, an ICE candidate may encompass a TURN server to use.

How the browser assigns this priority is left to the implementation. We would like to implement our own protocol.

If we can calculate such a priority, how can we influence the browser to use our priority when sending ICE candidates?

Answer (score 1):

The priority of the TURN server is determined by the priority of the ICE candidate. That's right! And, as I googled, the text/document summarized for the priority of the ICE candidate was in Stack Overflow. Please read it once and refer to it:

> [How does WebRTC decide which TURN Servers to Use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26342589/how-does-webrtc-decide-which-turn-servers-to-use)

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I saw that. But is it possible to influence this decision via the WebRTC (js) API?