# STUN/TURN server connectivity test

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn

I am trying to figure out how to test whether a STUN/TURN server is alive and properly responding to connections. Ideally this test would be performed from an external machine, just in case the STUN/TURN machine is down for this case should also be reported by the connectivity test.

Has anyone looked into this case in the past? What solutions would be recommended?

Comment: You could just try and gather ICE candidates from it.

Answer (score 58):

**Edit:** A nice implementation in github.io taken from comment to another answer( choose "relay" in IceTransports value):

<kbd>[Test TURN Server](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/)</kbd>

---

following  Benjamin Trent's advice, I wrote the below code to test TURN server's connectivity, works on both firefox n chrome:

```js
function checkTURNServer(turnConfig, timeout){ 

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

    setTimeout(function(){
        if(promiseResolved) return;
        resolve(false);
        promiseResolved = true;
    }, timeout || 5000);

    var promiseResolved = false
      , myPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection   //compatibility for firefox and chrome
      , pc = new myPeerConnection({iceServers:[turnConfig]})
      , noop = function(){};
    pc.createDataChannel("");    //create a bogus data channel
    pc.createOffer(function(sdp){
      if(sdp.sdp.indexOf('typ relay') > -1){ // sometimes sdp contains the ice candidates...
        promiseResolved = true;
        resolve(true);
      }
      pc.setLocalDescription(sdp, noop, noop);
    }, noop);    // create offer and set local description
    pc.onicecandidate = function(ice){  //listen for candidate events
      if(promiseResolved || !ice || !ice.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate || !(ice.candidate.candidate.indexOf('typ relay')>-1))  return;
      promiseResolved = true;
      resolve(true);
    };
  });   
}
```

example usage:

```js
checkTURNServer({
    urls: 'turn:127.0.0.1',
    username: 'test',
    credential: 'test'
}).then(function(bool){
    console.log('is TURN server active? ', bool? 'yes':'no');
}).catch(console.error.bind(console));
```

You can run the below snippet to check:

```js
var res = id('result');

id('button').onclick = function(){
 res.innerHTML = 'Checking TURN Server...';
  var url = 'turn:'+id('url').value+':'+id('port').value,
    useUDP = id('udp').checked;
  url +='?transport=' + (useUDP ? 'udp': 'tcp');
  checkTURNServer({
      urls: url,
      username: id('name').value, 
      credential: id('pass').value
  }, id('time').value).then(function(bool){
    if(bool)
         res.innerHTML = 'Yep, the TURN server works...';
      else
         throw new Error('Doesn\'t work');
  }).catch(function(e){
    console.log(e);
     res.innerHTML = 'TURN server does not work.';
  });
};


function checkTURNServer(turnConfig, timeout){ 
 console.log('turnConfig: ', turnConfig);
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

    setTimeout(function(){
        if(promiseResolved) return;
        resolve(false);
        promiseResolved = true;
    }, timeout || 5000);

    var promiseResolved = false
      , myPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection   //compatibility for firefox and chrome
      , pc = new myPeerConnection({iceServers:[turnConfig]})
      , noop = function(){};
    pc.createDataChannel("");    //create a bogus data channel
    pc.createOffer(function(sdp){
      if(sdp.sdp.indexOf('typ relay') > -1){ // sometimes sdp contains the ice candidates...
        promiseResolved = true;
        resolve(true);
      }
      pc.setLocalDescription(sdp, noop, noop);
    }, noop);    // create offer and set local description
    pc.onicecandidate = function(ice){  //listen for candidate events
      if(promiseResolved || !ice || !ice.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate || !(ice.candidate.candidate.indexOf('typ relay')>-1))  return;
      promiseResolved = true;
      resolve(true);
    };
  });   
}


function id(val){
 return document.getElementById(val);
}
```

```css
#url{
  width: 250px;
}
#port{
  width: 70px;
}
```

```html
<h1>
 Test TURN server
</h1>
<div>
TURN URL: <input id='url' placeholder='example.com  or  xxx.yyy.rrr.ddd'  />
Port: <input type='number' value='3478' id='port' placeholder='enter a port number' />
</div>
<div>
Transport: <input type="radio" name="transport" id="tcp" value="tcp" /> TCP
<input type="radio" name="transport" id="udp" value="udp" checked/>UDP
</div>

<div>
Username: <input id="name" placeholder="turn username" />
</div>
<div>
password: <input id="pass" placeholder="turn password" />
</div>

<div>
checking Timeout: <input type='number'  id="time" placeholder="wait time  before checking timeout" value=5000 />
</div>
<div>
<button id='button'>
Check TURN Server
</button>
</div>

<h4 id='result'></h4>
```

Comment: What should be the output of gather candidate to make sure that stun or turn server is working. https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/

Comment: **Do not user `test` as username** as shown in the example.  Apparently there is some `test` user already implemented behind the scenes within the browsers, hence it is burnt and if you try it for your tests, things fail for no apparent reason.  I found no documentation about this behavior, though, but after using a different name, everything suddenly started to work ..

Comment: @mido could you please answer my question here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60946697/coturn-aws-ec2-problems-running

Answer (score 16):

The earlier answers work with TURN if you use a *username:password* authentication mechanism for your coturn server. However, as is the case for BigBlueButton and others using `static-auth-secret` as seen in `/etc/turnserver.conf`, it is not possible to use https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/.

```
use-auth-secret
static-auth-secret=XXXX
```

One way to still test your TURN server is to install `turnutils_uclient` with `sudo apt install coturn` or your respective package manager. You can then subsequently test it with (replace XXXX and turn.example.com):

```
turnutils_uclient -T -W XXXX turn.example.com
```

This should result in the following output (redacted IP addresses 192.168.0.2 as internal client address and 1.2.3.4 as the server address):

```
0: IPv4. Connected from: 192.168.0.2:50988
0: IPv4. Connected to: 1.2.3.4:3478
0: allocate sent
0: allocate response received: 
0: allocate sent
0: allocate response received: 
0: success
0: IPv4. Received relay addr: 1.2.3.4:56365
....
4: Total transmit time is 4
4: Total lost packets 0 (0.000000%), total send dropped 0 (0.000000%)
4: Average round trip delay 32.500000 ms; min = 15 ms, max = 56 ms
4: Average jitter 12.600000 ms; min = 0 ms, max = 41 ms
```

On your TURN server, this should be mirrored in `/var/log/coturn.log`.

Comment: Also there is turnutils_stunclient for stun: `turnutils_stunclient -p 3478 stunserver.com`

Comment: Without reading the RfCs, it seems to be possible to compute a temporarily valid user name based on the current time and the static secret: `secret=$(awk -F "=" '/^static-auth-secret/ {print $2}' /etc/turnserver.conf) && time=$(date +%s) && expiry=3600 && username=$(( $time + $expiry )) && echo username:$username && echo "password : $(echo -n $username | openssl dgst -binary -sha1 -hmac $secret | openssl base64)"`
Thanks to https://blog.wydler.eu/2020/04/04/eigener-turn-server-fuer-jitsi-meet-bereitstellen/ for this script. (Adjusted to work with commented-out static-auth-secret rows in conf)

Comment: Jupp, BigBlueButton also released a [script](https://docs.bigbluebutton.org/2.2/setup-turn-server.html#test-you-turn-server) for that purpose. It allows you to use the [Trickle ICE](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/) posted in another answer.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to check the stun server constantly you can execute this command with cron :

```
stunserver=stun1.l.google.com;stunport=19302;listenport=20000;echo -ne "\x00\x01\x00\x00YOGO\x59\x4f\x47\x4fSTACFLOW" | nc -u -p $listenport $stunserver $stunport -w 0;timeout 1 nc -l -u $listenport | head -c 32 | tail -c 4 | hexdump -e '/1 "%u" "."' | grep -o ".*[^.]" && echo yes-no-problem || mail -s "Error in Tun server:$stunserver:$stunport" root@localhost <<< 'Error in Tun server'
```

Replace root@localhost with your email to get the report.

stunserver=stun1.l.google.com;
stunport=19302;
listenport=20000; # Change freely this port if not available

Add it to cron and execute it every minute.

Comment: Also include port: `stunserver=stun.l.google.com;stunport=19302;listenport=20000;echo -ne "\x00\x01\x00\x000000000000000000" | nc -u -p $listenport $stunserver $stunport -w 0;timeout 1 nc -l -u $listenport | head -c 32 | tail -c 6 | hexdump -e '1/2 "%u:" 4/1 "%u."'`

Answer (score 1):

Version of @mido function to check the TURN and the STUN server both (original rejects stun-servers):

```
function checkTurnOrStun(turnConfig, timeout){ 
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

    setTimeout(function(){
        if(promiseResolved){
            if (promiseResolved == 'STUN') resolve('STUN');
            return;
        }
        resolve(false);
        promiseResolved = true;
    }, timeout || 5000);

    var promiseResolved = false
      , myPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection   //compatibility for firefox and chrome
      , pc = new myPeerConnection({iceServers:[turnConfig]})
      , noop = function(){};
    pc.createDataChannel("");    //create a bogus data channel
    pc.createOffer(function(sdp){
      if(sdp.sdp.indexOf('typ relay') > -1){ // sometimes sdp contains the ice candidates...
        promiseResolved = 'TURN'; 
        resolve(true);
      }
      pc.setLocalDescription(sdp, noop, noop);
    }, noop);    // create offer and set local description
    pc.onicecandidate = function(ice){  //listen for candidate events
      if( !ice || !ice.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate)  return;
      if (ice.candidate.candidate.indexOf('typ relay')!=-1) { promiseResolved = 'TURN'; resolve('TURN'); }
      else if (!promiseResolved && (ice.candidate.candidate.indexOf('typ prflx')!=-1 || ice.candidate.candidate.indexOf('typ srflx')!=-1)){
          promiseResolved = 'STUN';
        if (turnConfig.url.indexOf('turn:')!==0) resolve('STUN');
      }
      else return;
    };
  });   
}

checkTurnOrStun({"url": "stun:stunserver.org"}).then(function(result){
    console.log(
    result ? 'YES, Server active as '+result : 'NO, server not active');
}).catch(console.error.bind(console));

checkTurnOrStun({
            url: 'turn:numb.viagenie.ca',
            credential: 'muazkh',
            username: 'webrtc@live.com'
}).then(function(result){
    console.log(
    result ? 'YES, Server active as '+result : 'NO, server not active');
}).catch(console.error.bind(console));
```

Comment: even if stun server offline its shows that you have turn server on, but i dont

Comment: @waza123 If the turn server is not available say wrong credentials it reverts to 'active as STUN' if offline it will say: "NO, turn server not active"

Answer (score 0):

npm i stun

```
const stun = require('stun');

stun.request('stun.l.google.com:19302', (err, res) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    const { address } = res.getXorAddress();
    console.log('your ip', address);
  }
});
```

Comment: Nice :) Completely sufficient for a quick test

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cleaned up and modernized version of @mido's answer to check if the server is reachable. This is especially useful for private networks where an online tests fails.

It also prints the types of the candidates to the console.

**Function**

```js
const checkTURNServer = (turnConfig, timeout = 5000) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        const pc = new RTCPeerConnection({iceServers: [turnConfig]});
        let promiseResolved = false;
        // Stop waiting after X milliseconds and display the result
        setTimeout(() => {
            if(promiseResolved)
                return;
            promiseResolved = true;
            resolve(false);
        }, timeout);
        // Create a bogus data channel
        pc.createDataChannel('');
        // Listen for candidates
        pc.onicecandidate = ice => {
            if(promiseResolved || ice === null || ice.candidate === null)
                return;
            console.log(ice.candidate.type);
            if(ice.candidate.type === 'relay') {
                promiseResolved = true;
                resolve(true);
            }
        };
        // Create offer and set local description
        const offer = await pc.createOffer();
        await pc.setLocalDescription(offer);
    });
};
```

**Usage**

```js
checkTURNServer({
    urls: ['turn:' + location.host + ':3478', 'turns:' + location.host + ':5349'],
    username: "1604441890:myUser",
    credential: "myPassword",
    credentialType: 'password'
}).then(
    active => console.log('Is the TURN server active?', active ? 'Yes :)' : 'Not yet...keep trying ;)')
).catch(
    e => console.error(e)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

To check whether a TURN server is working or not you can use the turn server testing tool.

This testing tool lets you test between TURN server only, STUN server only or both TURN and STUN servers

1. Using the TURN server test: https://www.metered.ca/turn-server-testing

Comment: any affiliation with the linked tool? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Answer (score -1):

You could set up a 3rd party monitoring service (we use Monitis) or even your own machine to **PING** the server every minute from 1 or more locations. However this will only tell you if the server is ***reachable*** and not necessarily if the TURN/STUN application server still accepts & responds to TURN/STUN packets.

A server side monitoring library for STUN/TURN would make a great GitHub project.