# Cannot connect to TURN server when switching networks in Android Crosswalk

Tags: android, webrtc, crosswalk-runtime, crosswalk, peerjs

I'm developing a WebRTC calling app, and I'm facing some weird issues with it. I chose PeerJS to make all the development easier, and it works good.

But I have a weird problem when it comes to network switching on Android and Crosswalk (Wifi to 3G).

The thing is that I can make a call from one end to the other one over Wifi and it works as expected. Then I switch to 3G on one end, make another call and it doesn't work.

The issue is that, when it is working over 3G, one end does not receives relay candidates. So it answers to host candidate but not to relay candidates which are the ones that I want to.

```
{"type":"OFFER","payload":{"sdp":{"type":"offer","sdp":"v=0\r\no=- 9207325897229143904 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=group:BUNDLE audio\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS sEJdVRbesv0A43zVIHpsjpBP97JHsJsnvIXh\r\nm=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 9 0 8 106 105 13 126\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:XayiDeo/VebqhfvU\r\na=ice-pwd:nlhMhUoDBuMhQjeN7gVzmDZA\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 A4:12:DA:AD:0F:60:63:F1:A8:50:C2:57:98:89:ED:77:43:B4:CF:2E:AA:F5:53:A7:90:97:12:B6:58:82:27:1F\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=mid:audio\r\na=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level\r\na=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2\r\na=fmtp:111 minptime=10; useinbandfec=1\r\na=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000\r\na=rtpmap:9 G722/8000\r\na=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\r\na=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000\r\na=rtpmap:106 CN/32000\r\na=rtpmap:105 CN/16000\r\na=rtpmap:13 CN/8000\r\na=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000\r\na=maxptime:60\r\na=ssrc:157434490 cname:qDTW7PBlwzV52rEW\r\na=ssrc:157434490 msid:sEJdVRbesv0A43zVIHpsjpBP97JHsJsnvIXh fa7fe6f0-5372-4573-a76d-09ff3bd18948\r\na=ssrc:157434490 mslabel:sEJdVRbesv0A43zVIHpsjpBP97JHsJsnvIXh\r\na=ssrc:157434490 label:fa7fe6f0-5372-4573-a76d-09ff3bd18948\r\n"},"type":"media","connectionId":"mc_00787gz767gmn29","browser":"Chrome"},"dst":"ZUQn45fuzC"}

{"type":"CANDIDATE","payload":{"candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:3747612131 1 tcp 1518280447 192.168.1.42 0 typ host tcptype active generation 0","sdpMid":"audio","sdpMLineIndex":0},"type":"media","connectionId":"mc_00787gz767gmn29"},"dst":"ZUQn45fuzC"}

{"type":"CANDIDATE","payload":{"candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:3747612131 2 tcp 1518280446 192.168.1.42 0 typ host tcptype active generation 0","sdpMid":"audio","sdpMLineIndex":0},"type":"media","connectionId":"mc_00787gz767gmn29"},"dst":"ZUQn45fuzC"}

{"type":"ANSWER","src":"ZUQn45fuzC","dst":"ZUQn45fuzC-908sf","payload":{"sdp":{"type":"answer","sdp":"v=0\r\no=- 4572206596343832202 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=group:BUNDLE audio\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS vd1JxmlIr4LBan1PD5paXYyHfyUhw1vEJY3k\r\nm=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 9 0 8 106 105 13 126\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:mu+gTMWn5JTLdZvc\r\na=ice-pwd:jKodikIYat7TmAFstDOMkYLy\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 7B:95:5E:62:D3:09:E3:39:45:F2:03:54:40:07:17:1A:55:61:6D:AC:F0:B1:0E:95:2E:89:A0:D4:F6:8D:D7:BC\r\na=setup:active\r\na=mid:audio\r\na=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level\r\na=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2\r\na=fmtp:111 minptime=10; useinbandfec=1\r\na=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000\r\na=rtpmap:9 G722/8000\r\na=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\r\na=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000\r\na=rtpmap:106 CN/32000\r\na=rtpmap:105 CN/16000\r\na=rtpmap:13 CN/8000\r\na=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000\r\na=maxptime:60\r\na=ssrc:4261079885 cname:A48eZP6Rm+hQeX2p\r\na=ssrc:4261079885 msid:vd1JxmlIr4LBan1PD5paXYyHfyUhw1vEJY3k 60fbeb3f-0baf-4871-8be3-a5a2b002f4b0\r\na=ssrc:4261079885 mslabel:vd1JxmlIr4LBan1PD5paXYyHfyUhw1vEJY3k\r\na=ssrc:4261079885 label:60fbeb3f-0baf-4871-8be3-a5a2b002f4b0\r\n"},"type":"media","connectionId":"mc_00787gz767gmn29","browser":"Chrome"}}

{"type":"CANDIDATE","src":"ZUQn45fuzC","dst":"ZUQn45fuzC-908sf","payload":{"candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:1189248530 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.1.49 40726 typ host generation 0","sdpMid":"audio","sdpMLineIndex":0},"type":"media","connectionId":"mc_00787gz767gmn29"}}

{"type":"CANDIDATE","src":"ZUQn45fuzC","dst":"ZUQn45fuzC-908sf","payload":{"candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:2968651718 1 udp 1686052607 83.40.XXX.XXX 40726 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.49 rport 40726 generation 0","sdpMid":"audio","sdpMLineIndex":0},"type":"media","connectionId":"mc_00787gz767gmn29"}}

{"type":"CANDIDATE","src":"ZUQn45fuzC","dst":"ZUQn45fuzC-908sf","payload":{"candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:140608226 1 tcp 1518280447 192.168.1.49 0 typ host tcptype active generation 0","sdpMid":"audio","sdpMLineIndex":0},"type":"media","connectionId":"mc_00787gz767gmn29"}}

{"type":"CANDIDATE","src":"ZUQn45fuzC","dst":"ZUQn45fuzC-908sf","payload":{"candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:729144661 1 udp 41885439 188.XXX.XXX.XXX 49360 typ relay raddr 83.40.XXX.XXX rport 40726 generation 0","sdpMid":"audio","sdpMLineIndex":0},"type":"media","connectionId":"mc_00787gz767gmn29"}}
```

I tested the connectivity between the TURN server and the device with [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28772212/stun-turn-server-connectivity-test), and it told me that the turn server was not available. When I switch back to Wifi everything works properly.

Is there any issue with android crosswalk with WebRTC? What could be happening here?. I have crosswalk version 18.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you found anything yet ? I am also facing the same issue...

Comment: I have not found any solution yet. It is a native webkit issue, I posted an issue in the Crosswalk bugtracker. You can follow it here https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-6894