# How do i know which STUN server responded in iceServers list webRTC

Tags: webrtc, stun

Is there an option to see which STUN server responded while i put list of urls inside iceServers?

Use cases:

1. Which one is responding slower.
2. Want to identify which `STUN` server is down.

If i could see a stun server identity in response header or an order number of the response this becomes easy.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sasivarunan/6nebr2a4/2/) to understand.

This is not a dupe of [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28772212/stun-turn-server-connectivity-test), 
Currently i've to pick each stun server separately and create a RTCPeerconnection to see the response.

Comment: I think this is a dup. No, there's no special API for this. I recommend using them one at a time and compare. As long as you're using trickle ICE, this shouldn't matter much to connection time anyway.

Comment: @jib My idea was to detect the fast responding or near by Media server by running STUN server instances in all my Media server and make use of RTCPeerconnection with STUN server list and check for response header

Answer (score 0):

I'm using WebRTC SDKs in Android & iOS and they come with a property in the ICE candidate class with the specific STUN server's URL for each candidate.

For example, in Android, class org.webrtc.IceCandidate contains:

```
public final String serverUrl;
```

I haven't found an equivalent field in RTCIceCandidate class in the browsers (Chrome & Firefox).

Hope this helps (at least if you are developing for Android & iOS).