# Coturn AWS EC2 problems running

Tags: amazon-ec2, webrtc, coturn

I'm trying to setup and run coturn TURN server on my EC2 instance which is on ubuntu. I have installed coturn package and trying to run the server using command line only and here is my command -

```
sudo turnserver -a -syslog -o -n -u [My_Username]:[My_Password] -f -p 3478 -L [AWS_Internal_IP] -X [AWS_External_IP] -r [AWS_External_IP]  -v --no-dtls --no-tls -—no-cli
```

I get `turnserver invalid option -- '?'`

and the server does not run. Please help.

Comment: I don't have a solution to your direct issue, but as Hoang said, a config file is better. You can see an example here: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/1175/how-to-create-and-configure-your-own-stun-turn-server-with-coturn-in-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 0):

You should configure coturn in config file (/etc/turnserver.conf).

Answer (score 0):

The last argument in your call to coturn does not start with a double dash, but with a dash and an em-dash.